# Does the Off Topic please ask on... need another entry?

Tags: discussion

[Just had this review.](https://askubuntu.com/review/close/428326)

It was someone wanting to but the Ubuntu phone and remove Ubuntu from it. This belongs on Android Enthusiasts I guess.

Do we need to add (now we support Ubuntu touch) a link to the mobile sites?

Comment: It also fits just as easily in [su], so even though Android has a dedicated Stack Exchange, I feel we have covered that area.